# group markers in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers

I found this great tutorial it works perfectly.
http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/ipmapper/

Here is the javascript code which returnred lat&lon values from an IP address:
http://pastebin.com/1gE91nuh

So there are a lot of markers in the same place and I would like to make groups something like this:
 http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/examples/simple_example.html

Example: 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/docs/examples.html

But somebody could help me how to make groups in the original code? ( original code: http://pastebin.com/1gE91nuh )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that creates the marker clusters. When markers are created, they are pushed into an array. That array is passed into a new MarkerClusterer object.

```
  function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
          dataPhoto.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: ok thanks but in my code, what I should write in the MarkerClusterer() ?

Comment: Line 27: `var c=new google.maps.Marker({map:IPMapper.map,draggable:false,position:g});`

Make sure to push this Marker onto your Marker array. I am not sure exactly where your code stores the google.maps.Map object. Once you have figured that out, simply: `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(google.maps.Map, [google.maps.Marker]);`

Comment: I refreshed my code: http://pastebin.com/1gE91nuh
I add 68. line but it doesn't work and I dont know why dont work... Have you any idea?

Comment: I created a new question, pls see it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057252/make-groups-for-markers-in-google-map-apiv3