# make groups for markers in google map apiV3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I found a very good tutorial which put the markers from any IP address. (google maps) http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/ipmapper/

I would like to modify this code: http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/ipmapper/ipmapper.htm . I have more than 500 markers in the same area, and I would like to make groups, something like this:
 http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/examples/simple_example.html

So I modified the original code I put the 37. Line this code:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(IPMapper.map, ipArray);
```

I think this line make the groups, but nothing happened.

Can anybody help me what do I wrong?

Comment: Are you subsequently adding the markerCluster to the map?

Comment: yes! here are my codes: HTML: http://pastebin.com/UXgAxGw9 ; and the ipmapper.js: http://pastebin.com/jdMPbEU4

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to instantiate an array just before you start calling addIpMarker.

Remove line 57 and instead create a new Google maps marker, it's called in a loop so it will create a new marker for each ip.

Push this marker to the array you initially created so that when the loop ends you have an array of markers.

Then call: var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(yourMap, yourNewArray).

Previously you were passing the array of ip addresses to the marker cluster rather than an array of markers, while the addIPMarker function was adding them independently to the map.

Hope this helps.

PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/0fteg7g1 to fix.

Comment: What you've actually done is used the default function to add the markers on line 57 (IPMapper.placeIPMarker(marker, latlng, contentString); This is adding a single marker to the map at the coordinates specified by the geocoding request)

And then added the array of ip addresses (not markers) to the marker cluster. The cluster then cannot plot them as they are not markers.

Comment: thanks but I am very very new in google maps api. Could you fix my code on pastebin and repost the link?

Comment: I've altered the code in the pastebin and put it in the answer, however I'm unsure as to how the ipmapper library works, so any other issues with implementing this I may not be able to help with. Also you'll need to include the markerClusterer library.

Comment: thanks.
I get this error line 58. Uncaught ReferenceError: markerArray is not defined

Comment: Define the array globally just after the comments at the top instead of on line 34.

Comment: The second push is not related to the markers, it is used as part of a function to filter an array to find unique elements (to avoid duplicate plotting). Don't worry about that one, it's working correctly.

Comment: The two push methods are unrelated, they're working on separate arrays. All push does is add a specified item to an array in the last position, there is no way the two will interact as the arrays they are operating on are different.

Comment: Here is my latest javascript code: http://pastebin.com/iAmyYnVB and the HTML http://pastebin.com/UXgAxGw9 Please try it, it not works for me.

Comment: You're importing markerClusterer twice in the HTML, remove the src on line 14. Other than that I'm not sure I can be of any more help, I've never used the ipmapper library. What's the error?